# Library function objdump output

Tags: c++, c, arm, objdump

I have the following objdump output when debugging a crash. I could narrow down the issue to the following function `LanManager::Interface()` library function, but with my little experience with object code I haven't been able to work out much more sense from the objdump output.

Below is the beginning part of that library function. I'd like to know:

- Whether the beginning address is the address of the function itself?
- What is the relation of that function address and the address of the main executable that uses the function?
- A brief explanation of the three columns in this objdump output.
- What is `_init`? Is that the beginning of the function?
- Is there any way to work out what `<_init+0x10e4>` is pointing to?

I won't expect a complete answer, just anything that sheds some light would be appreciated.

---

```
0003629c <LanManager::Interface()>:
   3629c:   e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
   362a0:   e92dd9f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, fp, ip, lr, pc}
   362a4:   e59f40b8    ldr r4, [pc, #184]  ; 36364 <LanManager::Interface()+0xc8>
   362a8:   e24cb004    sub fp, ip, #4  ; 0x4
   362ac:   e24dd004    sub sp, sp, #4  ; 0x4
   362b0:   e59f70b0    ldr r7, [pc, #176]  ; 36368 <LanManager::Interface()+0xcc>
   362b4:   e08f4004    add r4, pc, r4
   362b8:   e59f50ac    ldr r5, [pc, #172]  ; 3636c <LanManager::Interface()+0xd0>
   362bc:   e7940007    ldr r0, [r4, r7]
   362c0:   ebff6dc9    bl  119ec <_init+0x10e4>
   362c4:   e7942005    ldr r2, [r4, r5]
   362c8:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
   362cc:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0  ; 0x0
   362d0:   0a000005    beq 362ec <LanManager::Interface()+0x50>
   362d4:   e7943005    ldr r3, [r4, r5]
   362d8:   e7940007    ldr r0, [r4, r7]
   362dc:   e5934000    ldr r4, [r3]
```

Comment: `static` functions will not have a name to use in disassembler.  Disassembly like `bl  119ec <_init+0x10e4>` indicates some static function that follows `init` in the *.text* segment. Objdump puts labels where an elf says the function begins.  Also, `LanManager::Interface()` is a typical prologue on the ARM EABI.  You can disassemble `init+0x10e4` to see what it does; if it calls functions, this will help.  The values `ldr r4, [pc, #184]  ; 36364` are loading constants and you can see the with `--disassemble-all`; they maybe function pointers.  The `init+0x10e4` may just be a veneer.

Comment: @artlessnoise: could you advise how to "disassemble init+0x10e4"?

Comment: Disassemble the whole library/elf to a file.  Use `--disassemble-all` and then search for `init`.  Go to `init+0x10e4` and look to see something like `mov ip,sp` or at least saving registers (you have disassembled everything, so you have it).  Or it might be just a short snippet that jumps elsewhere.  It might be *got* or *plt* related; these jump to other libraries.

Comment: thanks; my `<_init>` looks very thin like below (sorry I don't know how to align it properly in comment), so seems like it jumped to another library?

`00010908 <_init>:
   10908: e52de004  push {lr}  ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
   1090c: e24dd004  sub sp, sp, #4 ; 0x4
   10910: eb000549  bl 11e3c <call_gmon_start>
   10914: e28dd004  add sp, sp, #4 ; 0x4
   10918: e8bd8000  pop {pc}
Disassembly of section .plt:`

Comment: If `init` is at 0x10908, then the routine is at 0x10908+10e4=0x119ec.  This is the address you need to disassemble.  Section `plt` info can be found in the [arm ELF spec](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf), under section 3.1.3.  It provides a function call outside the library.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to shed a little light here, but for more depth you may want to check out a text on assembly programming in ARM or reverse engineering.

You're looking at the disassembly for `LanManager::Interface`. Yes, `0003629c` is the value of the function pointer itself. Your three columns look like:

| address | opcodes | disassembly |

`_init` is another symbol somewhere in the file you disassembled. It seems kinda weird that LanManager::Interface would branch to some location a whole page away from the start of another function.

When a binary has had its symbols stripped, and objdump is trying to determine the symbolic name for an address, it will keep scanning backwards until it eventually finds one. Likely that `_init` is just the entry point or something, I've forgotten the names emitted by the compiler off the top of my head.

You can poke around in gdb and disassemble specific addresses with `(gdb) disas *0x119ec`. However you really never say what sort of crash you're looking at in the first place... if you wrote a program that's dying on a library call I would spend more time looking at arguments you passed in.

Comment: any link/document to start with that ARM assembly/reverse engineering you may recommend?

Comment: This book may be a good start: http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Reverse-Engineering-Reversing-Obfuscation/dp/1118787315/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1449205791&sr=1-1&keywords=reverse+engineering

You can get reference manuals on the ARM architecture from ARM themselves: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html